# Extracting different vectors from a single column of data (in R)

Tags: r

I have a small problem, which I don't think is too hard, but I couldn't find any answer here (maybe I phrased my research wrong so please excuse me if the question has already been asked!)

I am importing data from an excel sheet which is split in two columns as in the following picture:

[image]

Now,  I am trying to import all the data in the second column to my R script, but by splitting it into different vectors: one vector for category A, one for category B, etc... by keeping the data points in the order they are in the file (because as it happens, they are in chronological order).

Now, the categories each have a different number of elements, however, they are ordered alphabetically (ie you'll never find an A in the B's, for example). So I guess that makes it easier,  but I'm still a novice with R and I don't really know how to proceed without getting really messy with the code and I know there's probably a simple way of doing it.

Does anyone have an idea on how to treat this nicely please? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `split` in `base R` to return a `list` of `vector`s of 'Data' based on the unique values in 'Category'

```
lst1 <- split(df1$Data, df1$Category)
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver! Thank you, this is exactly what I needed :D

Comment: Don't worry, I will! You need to wait 15 minutes before accepting an answer ^^*